# AnyswapV5ERC20 deployment - set totalSupply

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, nodejs, chaindata, cross-chain

I have some questions about the anyswapV5ERC20.sol contract.

First of all, are there some more detailed docs than the guide of andre cronje?

My main question is: How can I set the totalSupply or mint at deployment when I follow this guide (https://andrecronje.medium.com/deploying-your-own-cross-chain-token-101-240420efd0d9)

If I understand the contract right, the minter role is the given mpc address and that which mint/burn depending on the bridge use. But how can I set the initial supply? Is there another way then wrap an existing ERC20 for the anyswap contract without changing the anyswapV5ERC20.sol (like mint in the constructor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically Andre Cronje is saying that in order to have token compliant with the cross-chain swaps your token must inherit the `AnyswapV5ERC20` class from the `AnyswapV5ERC20.sol`.

```
contract MyCrossChainERC20 is AnyswapV5ERC20 {
    constructor() AnyswapV5ERC20("Token Name", "Token Symbol", "Decimals", "Address to real erc20 token or zero address", "Vault address") { }
}
```

The total supply of the `MyCrossChainERC20` is a dynamic value which is increased by the functions:

1. `mint(address to, uint256 amount)`
2. all `deposit` methods
3. `Swapin(bytes32 txhash, address account, uint256 amount)` - this is the cross-chain functionality

Also the totalSupply is decreased by the following functions:

1. `burn(address to, uint256 amount)`
2. all `withdraw`  methods
3. `Swapout(uint256 amount, address bindaddr)` - this is the cross-chain functionality